# Tex capacity exceeded by using renewcommand to add arguments into a list

Tags: macros, errors

I was working on a small macro in which I create a `\newcommand` with two arguments. The second argument is just a name. I want to use this `\newcommand` more than once and at the end I would like to have a complete list of all the second arguments used. It works when I use it once or twice, but fails when I use it three times and reports the tex capacity exceeded. Is there something I can do about it? Here is a little example, which illustrates the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\List}{}
\newcommand{\names}[2]{%
\foreach \i in {#1} {%
    \i~belongs in #2.\par
    }
\let\OldList\List
\ifthenelse{\equal{\OldList}{}}{\renewcommand{\List}{#2}}{\renewcommand{\List}{\OldList ,#2}}
}

\begin{document}
\names{Paul,Peter,Hans}{group1}
\names{Erik,Robert}{group2}
%\names{Alex,Robin,Klaus}{group3}          %uncomment this line to produce error

The following groups participate: \List
\end{document}
```

Comment: For working with lists you may consider the commands from `etoolbox ` too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest the well-defined/tested macros from `etoolbox`.

With `\listgadd{\List}{}` it's possible to define a list.

A comma separated value list can be added with `\forcsvlist{\listgadd{\List}}{#1}`, for example.

With a macro `\shownames[2]` one can loop through the list, the current list entry is contained in the **last** parameter of the macro via

```
\forlistloop{\shownames{#1}}{\List}
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}%

\listgadd{\List}{} % Dummy list
\listgadd{\GroupList}{} % Dummy list


\newcommand{\shownames}[2]{%
#2 belongs in #1\par
}%

\newcommand{\showallnames}[1]{%
  #1\par
}%

\newcommand{\List}{}
\newcommand{\names}[2]{%
  \forcsvlist{\listgadd{\List}}{#1}%
  \forcsvlist{\listgadd{\GroupList}}{#2}%
  \forlistloop{\shownames{#2}}{\List}%
}%


\begin{document}
\names{Paul,Peter,Hans}{group1}
\names{Erik,Robert}{group2}
\names{Alex,Robin,Klaus}{group3}          

The following groups participate:

\forlistloop{\showallnames}{\GroupList}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Those blank lines in the definitions bother me.

Comment: @egreg: I can use `\par` of course ;-)

Comment: I just had a quick look at the `etoolbox`. It certainly seems useful. Thanks!

Comment: @Gilean0709: You're welcome ;-)

Comment: after a longer look at `etoolbox` this one was the best choice for using the resulting list, because it makes it very easy to use it with further commands

Comment: @Gilean0709: Well, if sometimes the documentation is a little bit scarce, but if you have questions, come back and ask -- I'll try to answer then ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Let's see what happens. With the first `\names{Paul,Peter,Hans}{group1}` command, you redefine `\List` to contain `group1`. With the second `\names{Erik,Robert}{group2}`, `\List` is not empty any more, so you define it to be

```
\OldList,group2
```

where `\OldList` expands to `group1`.

Now the problem appears: with the third command you're doing `\let\OldList\List`, so `\OldList` will expand to `\OldList,group2` and, when

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\OldList}{}
```

is performed, LaTeX wants to expand “all the way”: so it expands `\OldList,group2` which expands to `\OldList,group2,group2`, which expands to … Bingo! Infinite loop. You're basically trying to fill a bottle not with the wine from another bottle, but with the other bottle itself!

A better procedure is getting the expansion of `\List` instead: no `\let\OldList\List`, but just

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\List}{}}
  {\renewcommand{\List}{#2}}
  {\expandafter\renewcommand\expandafter\List\expandafter{\List,#2}}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you define `\OldList` to be the contents of `\List` rather than trying to make it the same macro. (Note: somebody else will be able to explain this better!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen,pgffor}

\newcommand{\List}{}
\newcommand{\names}[2]{%

\foreach \i in {#1} {%
    \i~belongs in #2.\par
    }
\ifthenelse{\equal{\List}{}}{\renewcommand{\List}{#2}}{\expandafter\renewcommand\expandafter\List\expandafter{\List, #2}}% safer (see comments) though I don't actually understand why
}

\begin{document}
\names{Paul,P\'eter,Hans}{group1}
\names{Erik,Robert}{group2}
\names{Alex,Robin,Klaus}{group3}

The following groups participate: \List

\end{document}
```

I removed `tikz` only because it is mostly irrelevant to your MWE and a large package to load unnecessarily! But as cgnieder pointed out, you do need `pgffor` so I've substituted this.

[image: group demo]

Comment: Without TikZ (or rather `pgffor`) the code will result it `! Undefined control sequence. ... \foreach`.

Comment: @cgnieder Oops. You are right. I was confusing it with something else. I've added `pgffor` but still dropped `tikz` since it seems overkill just to get the looping.

Comment: `\expandafter\renewcommand\expandafter\List\expandafter{\List, #2}` is *much* safer.

Comment: @cgnieder thanks that works. I actually need tikz for what I am actually trying, therefore I left it in the code, but yes for my example here you are right.

Comment: @cfr Try with `\names{Paul,P\'eter,Hans}{group1}`.

Comment: @egreg What am I looking for? The output looks identical whether I use the code above or the replacement.

Comment: @cfr because `\edef` does exhaustive expansion which might lead to trouble. The `\expandafter` chain only expands the `\List` once so trouble is much less likely.

Comment: @cfr I used the wrong example: try `\names{A,B}{gr\'oup}`

Comment: @egreg I've changed the code but I still don't understand why. I tried that example, too, and I still get the same output whether I use `\edef` or the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `expl3` version of your code. The `\List` macro removes all duplicates from the list of groups, such that you can do `\names{...}{groupX}` twice without having `groupX` twice in the output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_gilean_groups_seq

\NewDocumentCommand \names { m m }
 {
  \gilean_names:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \List { }
 {
  \par
  \seq_remove_duplicates:N \l_gilean_groups_seq
  \seq_use:Nn \l_gilean_groups_seq { \par }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \gilean_names:nn #1#2
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    ##1 ~ belongs ~ in ~ #2 \par
   }
   \seq_put_right:Nn \l_gilean_groups_seq { #2 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\names{Paul,Peter,Hans}{group1}
\names{Erik,Robert}{group2}
\names{Alex,Robin,Klaus}{group3}
\names{Max,Donald,Robert}{group1}
The following groups participate: \List
\end{document}
```

> [image]

## List individual groups

We now have `\listgroups[<separator>]` which lists all groups and takes the separator as optional argument. Also there is `\listnames[<separator>]{<group>}` which lists all members of `<group>`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_gilean_names_seq
\seq_new:N \l_gilean_groups_seq

\NewDocumentCommand \names { m m }
 {
  \gilean_names:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \listnames { O{\par} m }
 {
  \int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int
  \seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_gilean_names_seq
   {
    \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int
    \str_if_eq_x:nnT { #2 } { \seq_item:Nn \l_gilean_groups_seq { \l_tmpa_int } }
     { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { ##1 } }
   }
   \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \listgroups { O{\par} }
 {
  \group_begin:
  \seq_remove_duplicates:N \l_gilean_groups_seq
  \seq_use:Nn \l_gilean_groups_seq { #1 }
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \gilean_names:nn #1#2
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_gilean_names_seq  { ##1 }
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_gilean_groups_seq {  #2 }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\names{Paul,Peter,Hans}{group1}
\names{Erik,Robert}{group2}
\names{Alex,Robin,Klaus}{group3}
\names{Max,Donald,Robert}{group1}
The following groups exist:\par
\listgroups[, ]

These people are in group1:\par
\listnames[, ]{group1}

These people are in group2:\par
\listnames[, ]{group2}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks, this seems...interesting, perhaps if I have a long weekend I will try to understand it^^